# SequelizeDatabaseError: You need JSON-C for ST_GeomFromGeoJSON when I have JSON-C installed on centos

Tags: javascript, node.js, centos, sequelize.js

I am getting following error at my centos server:

```
npm-2 Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You need JSON-C for ST_GeomFromGeoJSON
npm-2     at Query.formatError (/home/centos/jobcue.com/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:357:14)
npm-2     at null.<anonymous> (/home/centos/jobcue.com/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:88:19)
npm-2     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
npm-2     at emit (events.js:169:7)
npm-2     at Query.handleError (/home/centos/jobcue.com/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:108:8)
npm-2     at null.<anonymous> (/home/centos/jobcue.com/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:171:26)
npm-2     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
npm-2     at emit (events.js:169:7)
npm-2     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/centos/jobcue.com/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:12)
npm-2     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
npm-2     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
npm-2     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
npm-2     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
npm-2     at TCP.onread (net.js:531:20)
```

When I tried to install json-c on server:

```
sudo yum install json-c
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.eecs.wsu.edu
 * epel: s3-mirror-us-west-2.fedoraproject.org
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * updates: mirror.raystedman.net
Package json-c-0.11-4.el7_0.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to be a postgis issue, I ended up building my postgis from source code. I had to configure my postgis with following command:

`./configure --with-jsonc=/usr/include`

If you like you can have a look at my full steps/ command logs at my blog:
http://www.sadafnoor.com/blog/centos-postgis-setup-you-need-json-c-for-st_geomfromgeojson/